# Меню выбора с++

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе пункта после операции программа опять возвращалась к выбору пункта, а не завершалассь

```
switch (variant) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Проматриваем содержимое..." << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Находим минимальный элемент..." << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Находим максимальный элемент..." << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Сортируем..." << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "Находим среднее количество элементов..." << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "Дополняем таблицу..." << endl;
        break;
    case 7:
        cout << "Выход из программы..." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
```

Comment: Затолкать выбор и обработку выбора в бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;
    bool check=true;
    while(check){
        cin >> a;
        switch(a){
            case 1:
                cout << "text" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```